# использование SharedPreference - не могу получить данные

Tags: eclipse

вопрос такой
класс меню запускает класс игры , там подставляется переменная для выбора уровня.
далее Context соответствующий этой переменной открывается.

класс меню - данные недоступны

```
public class LevelActivity extends Activity {

    private SharedPreferences preferences;
    private static final String LEVEL_NEXT = "LEVEL_NEXT";
    private static final String LEVELS_ALL = "LEVELS_ALL";
    private static final String SETTING_MISIC = "SETTING_MISIC";
    private static final String SETTING_SOUND = "SETTING_SOUND";

    public int level_next;
    public int levels_all;
    public int setting_music;
    public int setting_sound;
    Button bLevel1_12;
    Button bLevel13_24;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
        getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.level_all);
        preferences = getPreferences(0);
        levels_all = preferences.getInt(LEVELS_ALL, 0);
        level_next = preferences.getInt(LEVEL_NEXT, 0);
        setting_music = preferences.getInt(SETTING_MISIC, 0);
        setting_sound = preferences.getInt(SETTING_SOUND, 0);
```

переходим в класс игры (подставляется переменная) - данные доступны, уровни идут по порядку но не могу вывести в текствью

```
public class Game1_12 extends Activity{

    private SharedPreferences preferences;
    private static final String LEVEL_NEXT = "LEVEL_NEXT";
    private static final String LEVELS_ALL = "LEVELS_ALL";

    private int level_next;
    private int levels_all;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
       getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
       requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

       setContentView(R.layout.game_layout);

        preferences = getPreferences(0);
        level_next = preferences.getInt(LEVEL_NEXT, 0);

       RelativeLayout layout = 
               (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.game_relativelayuot);

       List<View> level_id = new ArrayList<>();
       level_id.add(new Level1(this, getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE), layout));
       level_id.add(new Level2(this, getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE), layout));

       layout.addView(level_id.get(level_next), 0);
```

теперь выводится класс игры - данные записываются но не могу вывести в текствью

```
public class Level1 extends View {

    private SharedPreferences preferences;
    private static final String LEVEL_NEXT = "LEVEL_NEXT";
    private static final String LEVELS_ALL = "LEVELS_ALL";
    private int level_next;
    private int levels_all;
    public Level1(Context context, SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, RelativeLayout layout) {
        super(context);
        preferences = sharedPreferences;
    }
    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
                    levels_all = 1;
                    level_next = 1;
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
                    editor.putInt(LEVEL_NEXT, level_next);
                    editor.putInt(LEVELS_ALL, levels_all);
                    editor.apply();
```

пробовал использовать модепривате но в классе игры эклипс просит объявить метод для getSharedPreference. В остальных классах ничего не работает. Ни запись ни чтение. При тестировании объем базы увеличивается в телефоне при записи а данные читать не могу.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отказался от ШаредПреф - просто сделал парсер и записывал результаты по строчно в файл на флешку.